# curl azure website ftps connection refused port 990

Tags: azure, curl, ftp, azure-web-app-service, ftps

I am trying to deploy azure websites via FTPS using curl. However, it throws error stating that

> Failed to connect to waws-prod-xxx-xxx-ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net
>   port 990: connection refused.

However, the same curl command works if i simply use ftp instead of ftps.

Answer (score 2):

@Sam, according to the section [`4.15 FTPS doesn't work`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#FTPS_doesn_t_work) of cURL FAQ, the issue should be caused by that the FTPS default port is 990, but still using port 21 on Azure, please see the explaination below.

> curl supports FTPS (sometimes known as FTP-SSL) both implicit and explicit mode.
>
> When a URL is used that starts with FTPS://, curl assumes implicit SSL on the control connection and will therefore immediately connect and try to speak SSL. FTPS:// connections default to port 990.
>
> To use explicit FTPS, you use a FTP:// URL and the --ftp-ssl option (or one of its related flavours). This is the most common method, and the one mandated by RFC4217. This kind of connection then of course uses the standard FTP port 21 by default.

So please try to add the `-k` & `--ftp-ssl` options and use the ftp url  to enable SSL for your curl command, for example, `curl -k --ftp-ssl -u '<webappname>\<username>:<password>' ftp://<hostname>.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/`

Comment: I tried `curl -u <cred> "ftp://xxx/NewDir/" --ftp-create-dirs --ftp-ssl -k`

Then I get this:


`curl: (7) Failed to connect to waws-prod-blu-037.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net port 21: Connection refused`

Answer (score 1):

Hi I found a solution randomly and Ill throw in the answer:

```
curl --ftp-ssl -T test.txt -k -u "<webappname>\<username>:<password>" "ftp://waws-prod-yt1-001.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net"
```

Running this on UNIX allows me to successfully connect. But on windows, it fails  with Connection Refused (port 21)

Turns out windows versions don't like double dash options "--ftp-ssl" and using one dash solved it!

```
curl -ftp-ssl -T test.txt -k -u "<webappname>\<username>:<password>" "ftp://waws-prod-yt1-001.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net"
```